# How can I make a multiline radio button label line up nicely?

Tags: html

I've got this fragment of automatically-generated HTML:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="question24_answer" value="A">A)&nbsp;
H<sub>0</sub>&#58; p = 0.0016<br/>H<sub>1</sub>&#58; p &lt; 0.0016</label>
```

This produces the following:

[image]

I'd like the two lines of the label to align vertically so they look good:

[image]

If necessary, the `A)` can be omitted, though I'd prefer not to:

[image]

Comment: You mention this is automatically-generated code. Is there any restrictions to changing the code because of this that we should be aware of?

Comment: @Alkarin, yes: I can't hand-tune each individual labeled radio button to look good.  Any solution needs to be something that can be done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> Any solution needs to be something that can be done automatically.

I believe that would rule out a pure HTML solution to which is the only tag your question has. So at the risk of ignoring the fact there's no CSS or JavaScript tag, I'll suggest JavaScript right off and a little bit of CSS.

1. `.querySelectorAll()` collects every `<br/>` that's a child of a `<label>` into a NodeList
2. `Array.prototype.map.call()`executes a function on each item of the NodeList and return a new array
3. `insertAdjacentHTML()` inserts a `<span>` after every `<br>` in the NodeList
4. This `<span>`'s width is 6.4ch; ch is a unit of measure equal to the width of a zero.
5. Use a monospaced font and make sure that `<input>` inherits font. These steps help normalize variances that fonts may cause.
6. To make it perfect, use a combination of `vertical-align` and `line-height` so the radio button is aligned properly.

**SNIPPET**

```js
var br = document.querySelectorAll('label br');

Array.prototype.map.call(br, function(obj) {
  return obj.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "<span class='ch'><span>")
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 400 16px/1.5 Consolas;
}

input {
  vertical-align: -10%;
  line-height: 1;
  font: inherit;
}

.ch {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 6.4ch;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="question24_answer" value="A">A)&nbsp;
H<sub>0</sub>&#58; p = 0.0016<br/>H<sub>1</sub>&#58; p &lt; 0.0016</label>
<br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="question24_answer" value="B">B)&nbsp;
H<sub>26</sub>&#58; p = 0.04096<br/>CH<sub>2</sub>&#58; p &lt; 0.096</label>
<br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="question24_answer" value="C">C)&nbsp;
H<sub>89</sub>&#58; p = 0.00248966652<br/>H<sub>1</sub>&#58; p &lt; 0.0016</label>
<br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="question24_answer" value="D">D)&nbsp;
H<sub>0</sub>&#58; p = 0.1<br/>H<sub>652</sub>&#58; p &lt; 0.0016</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, any visual changes you would like to make should be done with CSS.

However if this must be done with just html with no in-line styling, you can simply add some non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp`) to achieve this effect, along with an additional `<br>` tag.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="question24_answer" value="A">A)<br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
H<sub>0</sub>&#58; p = 0.0016<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;H<sub>1</sub>&#58; p &lt; 0.0016</label>
```

Which should give you this:

[image]

Alternatively if you want to use some in-line styling you could make use of the `float` property and place the second set of information in a `<div>` tag (or any semantic tag you deem fit):

```
<label style="float: left"><input type="radio" name="question24_answer" value="A">A)&nbsp;
<div style="float: right;">H<sub>0</sub>&#58; p = 0.0016<br/>H<sub>1</sub>&#58; p &lt; 0.0016</div></label>
```

Which should give you this:

[image]

Comment: The key attribute of a `<label>` is that you can click on it to activate the associated control.  Your "styled `<div>`" option breaks that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a list?

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="question24_answer" value="A">A)
<ul style="list-style: none; margin-top: 0;"><li>H<sub>0</sub>&#58; p = 0.0016</li><li>H<sub>1</sub>&#58; p &lt; 0.0016</li></label>
```